# trying requestAnimationFrame but it doesnt respond on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, scroll, requestanimationframe

I am trying to use `requestAnimationFrame` for scrolling animation in my Vue app, but it seems doesnt work what I write, I want to show the *Image* when that scroll on that element *Image*

in my Vue component is something like this

```
    data(){
      return {
         id: undefined,
       }
    },
    methods: {
      fancyFunction() {
          const elementToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".scrollPic");
          elementToShow.forEach(element => {
              if(this.isELementInViewPort(element)) {
                  console.log("correct")
                  element.classList.add('is-visible')
              }
          })
      },
      isELementInViewPort(el) {
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rect)
        return (
            (rect.top <= 0 && rect.bottom >= 0) ||
            (rect.bottom >= ( window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) ||
            (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= ( window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
        )
      }
    },
    }
    created() {
        this.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(
            this.fancyFunction
        )
    },
    destroyed() {
          window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
          this.id = undefined;
    }
```

why I use id ? because I want to that *function* `requestAnimationFrame` only work on that *component* and after that component left, I *destroy* that function to not running all the time , 
when I `console.log()` it doesnt watch what I a scrolling, it just read once on scroll 
what is the wrong on my code above ??

Comment: your `created` callback is being called only once right? Then your `fancyFunction` will also get called only once. If you wish to start a loop, you need to call `requestAnimationFrame( this.fancyFunction )` **from inside** `this.fancyFunction`.

Comment: it was solved by   `this.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(
            this.fancyFunction
        )`